# Business Logic in Netty?

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I'm developing a server based on the Netty libraby and I'm having a problem with how to structure the application with regards to business Logic.

currenty I have the business logic in the last handler and that's where I access the database. The thing I can't wrap my head around is the latency of accessing the database(blocking code). Is it advisable to do it in the handler or is there an alternative? code below:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
        throws Exception {
    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
    Msg message = (Msg)msg;
    switch(message.messageType){
        case MType.SIGN_UP:
            userReg.signUp(message.user);// blocking database access
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should execute the blocking calls  in `DefaultEventExecutorGroup` or your custom threadpool that can be added to when the handler is added

`pipeline.addLast(new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(50),"BUSSINESS_LOGIC_HANDLER", new BHandler());`

```
ctx.executor().execute(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //Blocking call
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom handler is initialized by Netty everytime the **Server** receives a request, hence one instance of the handler is responsible for handling one **Client**.

So, it is perfectly fine for issuing blocking calls in your handler. It will not affect other Client's, as long as you don't block it indefinitely (or atleast not for very long time), thereby not blocking Netty's Thread for long and you do not get too much load on your server instance.

However, if you want to go for **asynchronous design**, then there can be more than a few design patterns that you can use.

*For eg. with Netty, if you can implement **WebSockets**, then perhaps you can make the blocking calls in a separate Thread, and when the results are available, you can push them to the client through the WebSocket already established.*

Comment: your first solution don't  scale : if you got 100 client at time with blocking call you will end very soon with all the thread locked in the thread pool.(resulting in  every new conn wiating  for one another to finish) it will work for a very small app but not for a normal website, the first robot crawler comming will ddos your server

Comment: norman mauer says : http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#23.0